# Archivos renombrados con Files desaparencen

Tags: java, java-stream

Tengo un pequeño programa que cambia el nombre de los archivos dentro de un directorio que comienzan con un `string` especifico, al parecer funciona pero al terminar la ejecución, todos los archivos desaparecen, estoy en **ubuntu 18**

```
import java.io.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        File path = new File("/home/ivan/Downloads/copies/test"); //ruta

        File[] files = path.listFiles(); //array con los archivos que estan dentro de la ruta

        String[] filesName = path.list(); //array con el nombre de los archivos dentro de la ruta

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

            Boolean sucess = files[i].renameTo(new File(filesName[i].substring(13)));
            /*necesito eliminar los primeros 13 caracteres de cada archivo
            por eso uso el metodo substring(13))*/
            if (sucess == true)
            {
                System.out.println("worked!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("didnt work");
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Cómo te guarda los nombres de los ficheros en el array files? No te estará devolviendo la ruta completa de los ficheros y al quitar los 13 primeros caracteres le estés cambiando la ruta?

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba en:

`Boolean sucess = files[i].renameTo(new File(filesName[i].substring(13)));`

ya que no tomaba la ruta y por eso desaparecian los archivos, aqui el nuevo código que si funciona:

```
File path = new File("/home/ivan/Downloads/copies/test");

    File[] files = path.listFiles(); // ruta + nombre del archivo

    String[] filesName = path.list(); // nombre del archivo

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

        File[] newName = new File[files.length];

        newName[i] = new File(path + "/" + filesName[i].substring(13));

        if (files[i].renameTo(newName[i])) {
            System.out.println("worked!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("didnt work");
        }

    }

}
```